# Is something "candidate" or "candidated" to become a standard?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, past-participles

The context is technical in the IT field. Taking for example the `https` protocol would you say:

```
The https protocol is candidate to become in the main standard
```

or

```
The https protocol is candidated to become the main standard.
```

To me it seems `candidate` is more suitable for people rather than for things.

Also is `to` the right preposition?

Comment: You're *completely* mistaken in supposing that [***candidate***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22candidate+for+dark+matter%22) is somehow restricted to *people* (that link is to almost 3000 written instances of ***candidate for dark matter*** in Google Books). And there's nothing remotely unusual about "verbifying" English words which are normally used as nouns (or vice-versa). In fact, your second example looks more like something a native Anglophone might actually say than the first one (*inter alia,* native speakers would ***never*** omit the article in ***a** candidate* there).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are you saying a native speaker would rather say `The https protocol is candidated...`? That is my second example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Candidate* is normally a noun, not an adjective, or past participle.

Here's how *Merriam Webster* defines it

> **candidate** noun
>
> **1 a**  : one that aspires to or is nominated or qualified for an office, membership, or award
>  //a candidate for governor
>  //a candidate for "Manager of the Year"
>  //the best candidate for the job
>
> **b** : one likely or suited to undergo or be chosen for something specified 
> //a candidate for surgery
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidate

The second definition fits this context: "The https protocol is **a** candidate to become the main standard" or "The https protocol is a candidate for the main standard."

Comment: Thanks. However the verb `to candidate` exist (doesn't it?) so its pp too

Comment: @FrancescoBoi, I've never heard anyone use *candidate* as a verb and the only source I can find noting its existence is Wiktionary, which lists it as "uncommon" or "nonstandard, chiefly in jargon and by non-native speakers." Practically every word *can* be a verb, but that doesn't mean it should be.

Answer (score 2):

> The https protocol is candidate to become in the main standard.

Putting on my translator's hat here, I see what the OP is getting at.

And I think in English we would say here:

> The https protocol ***is slated*** to become the main standard.

MERRIAM WEBSTER
slate verb (1)
slated; slating
Definition of slate (Entry 2 of 3)
transitive verb

1 : to cover (something) with slate or a slatelike substance
slate a roof

> 2 : to designate (someone or something) for a specified purpose or
>   action occurring especially at a fixed time //was slated to direct the
>   play The new model is slated [=scheduled] for release early next year.

So, to be slated to become something means 2. And often, in times past, the names of candidates were written in chalk on a blackboard. That's where the expression comes from. Now, in writing, it can apply to people or things that are designated for a specific purpose.

English creates many verbs from nouns. However, candidate is not one of them. In Spanish, French, Portuguese (and probably Italian), there is a verb associated with noun: candidatarse, se candidater, and se candidatar.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to coin a verb from a noun or adjective, and that happens rather a lot in subcultures with their own jargon.

> Shall we obsolete this function?
>
> Should we candidate  14.5.35674?

Such coinages may strike the ears of speakers outside the subculture as ungrammatical.

Comment: `obsolete` is good counter-example. Thanks